# ajaxing data and displaying

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display some xml data from remote URL using jquery and ajax. In my xml, there are simply two elements to be accessed: `title` and `url`.

The structure of my xml file is as follows:

```
<list>
  <lists>
   <songs>
   <title>Pumped Up Kicks - Foster the people</title>       
   <url>http://dc249.4shared.com/img/970884399/8b9afc1d/dlink__2Fdownload_2Fmf4-        10b_5F_3Ftsid_3D20111122-112912-f675aa20/preview.mp3</url>
  </songs>
 </lists>
</list>
```

And I have the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://jeewanaryal.web44.net/SongsXML/nepaliSongs.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            var items = parseXml(xml);
            doStuff(items);
        }
    });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    var items = [];
    $(xml).find("songs").each(function () {
        items.push({
            name: $(this).find("title").text(),
            value: $(this).find("url").text()
        });
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        $(".phoneGapAPI").append(items[i].name + " <button class=\"newsDiv\" onclick=\"openChildBrowser(" + items[i].value + ");\">click here</button> <br> <br />");
    }
}
```

I can guess that I am doing wrong at the statement `openChildBrowser("+items[i].value+");`
How can I implement this? I need to pass the variable `items[i].value` inside the function `openChildBrowser()`.
This code works fine displaying `items[i].name` but click here link does not let me to open that URL.

Comment: `I can guess that I am doing wrong ` Why? _What happens?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery failed to to render your Xml (Error : XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{9e622e17-2e96-4a4d-95e4-6f7b95d0b4d8} Line Number 1, Column 1:) .Try to add version information to that xml file.

like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Comment: It displays the title but i could not access the url that I want to make hiperlink to that button. Its not about parsing XML problem, its just about the url element. I am doing wrong while passing the argument items[i].value inside the openChildBrowser function.